# Is this approach to weight loss fine?

Tags: weight-loss, diet, calories

I am trying to get lean, but I cannot track my macronutrients. So instead, to induce a caloric deficit, I'm simply just eating less and eating nutrient-dense healthy foods, prioritizing protein-rich foods. I also do not have access to a local gym so I'm doing a 6-day push-pull-legs workout split at home with some equipment. I will also do fasted cardio to burn fat.

In conclusion, is my approach to weight loss fine? Thank you

Comment: Are you counting your calories? Also why aren't you able to track your macro's? Pretty much all store-bought food these days lists all the necessary macronutrients on the back, so it's pretty easy to do.

Answer (score 2):

> I cannot track my macronutrients

That's fine. Tracking is simply a tool that helps people lose weight.  It's not for everyone, and it's not necessary.

> eating nutrient-dense healthy foods, prioritizing protein-rich foods

That is an excellent way to help lose weight. Protein-rich and high-fiber diets are very satiating and satisfying, so you may find that you end up eating less without much effort.

Low-calorie, high-volume foods like fruits and vegetables can help satisfy cravings as well as being healthy in general.

> 6-day push-pull-legs workout split at home with some equipment.

That's good.  A resistance program will help maintain and even build muscle mass which can be beneficial in the long-run for keeping weight off.

> I will also do fasted cardio to burn fat.

Cardio is helpful. You do not need to do it fasted if you do not like it. Fasted cardio will not help with fat loss, but if you prefer doing cardio fasted then go for it.

The most important thing is that you find something that you can stick to in a long term and be consistent. Weight loss is unfortunately a very slow process. Once you reach your goal you can't really just stop and go back to normal.

Not tracking can make it hard to stay consistent, but that would only slow progress, not stop it. As long as you enjoy what you're doing then the progress will come.